# iPad Development detecting the device's version

Tags: ipad, ios, ios-4.2

I have an iPad app that makes use in UIPrintInfo (that is being supported from iOS 4.2 and above).
I want my app to run on previous iOS version such as 3.2.
How can I detect in my code the device's iOS version and make the necessary changes according to the device's version?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]

Answer (score 3):

```
Class printInfoClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIPrintInfo");

if (printInfoClass != nil )
{
id printInfo = [printInfoClass printInfo];
// Do something
}
```

Comment: And printInfoClass will then be the UIPrintInfo metaclass. So you can use [[printInfo alloc] init] to get an instance of UIPrintInfo (or even [[NSClassFromString(@"UIPrintInfo") alloc] init] as a drop-in replacement for [[UIPrintInfo alloc] init], since messaging nil is safe). Just worth saying because the Smalltalk approach to metaclasses, as adopted by Objective-C, varies a bit from languages like C++.

Comment: Thanks! How can I detect the device version?

Comment: Don't check for the version. Instead, check for the features you care about.